Trying to Install Fuzzy package in python environment and I'm receiving this error message indicates that the "Fuzzy TM" package is not found
The problem here is that the "Fuzzy TM" package is not readily available on the main Python package repository (PyPI), which is where pip typically retrieves packages from. This means that i cannot simply install the "Fuzzy TM" package using the standard pip install command.
(base) C:\Users\hp>pip install Fuzzy-TM>=0.4.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Fuzzy-TM (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Fuzzy-TM
I was expecting to install the package which is the"Fuzzy TM" package version 0.4.0 or higher required by "gensim" package, which is a popular natural language processing (NLP) library
Is there an alternative to this problem?
